# It is possible to say that if the canonical commutation relations aren't satisfied, then we cannot "study" the dynamics of a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator

The similarity between Hamiltonian mechanics and quantum mechanics is paramount. On one hand, it is quite clear to me that **the canonical relations in classical mechanics** just tells us:

> Given the pair (roughly, a coordinate chart for the phase space) of positions and momenta $(q^{i},p_{j})$, it was found that the obey:
>
> \begin{cases}\{ q^{i},q^{j} \}_{\mathrm{PB}}=\{ p_{i},p_{j} \}_{\mathrm{PB}} = 0 \\ \{ q^{i},p_{j} \}_{\mathrm{PB}} = \delta^{i}\hspace{0.3mm}_{j}, \tag{1}\end{cases}
>
> for another coordinate chart $(Q^{i}((q^{m},p_{n})),P_{j}(q^{n},p_{m}))$, it is necessary that they "maintain" the form of equations $(1)$, as:
>
> \begin{cases}\{ Q^{i},Q^{j} \}_{\mathrm{PB}}=\{ P_{i},P_{j} \}_{\mathrm{PB}} = 0 \\ \{ Q^{i},P_{j} \}_{\mathrm{PB}} = \delta^{i}\hspace{0.3mm}_{j}. \tag{2}\end{cases}
>
> **If we have the "coordinate independece" given by $(2)$, then the same equations of motion, for both the Hamiltonian and for a observable $F$, is guaranteed; i.e.**
>
> $$\frac{\partial H}{\partial P} = \dot{Q}, \frac{\partial H}{\partial Q} = -\dot{P} \tag{3}$$
>
> **and**
> $$\frac{d f}{d t} = \{f,H\}_{\mathrm{PB}} \tag{4}$$
>
> **are validy just if we have coodinate independence just like $(2)$.**

A similar picture is drawn for quantum mechanics of one, finitely many and infinite degrees of freedom (the later is roughly the prototype for Quantum field theory).

My question is: when the textbook says "I postulate the commutation relations for the fields" or "the annihilation and creation operators satisfy the commutation relations", can I interpret these statements as:

> "I must to fulfill commutation relations because if not the Heisenberg dynamical equation is useless, then I can't do quantum field theory"?

The question is a bit odd, but I think it makes sense because, often the one starts with a classical field equation, then writes the field in terms of annihilation/creation operators (this is basically a coordinate change); since the one postulated that the fields satisfy the commutation relations the fields satisfy the Heisenberg equation. Then the one searches if the annihilation/creation operators also satisfies the commutation relations, rendering a easier Hamiltonian. Therefore, the whole procedure is somekind of a big "coordinate changing". Then, we define a well-posed quantum framework.

Comment: Quote from which textbook? Which page?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation) or the related procedure of [bosonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosonization) which allow us to transform the degrees of freedom in our system into a new representation in terms of degrees of freedom obeying commutation relations?

Comment: Walter greiner "Field Quantization", 1996.

1) For the Schröedinger fields (scalar wave functions) page 58, section 3.2

2) For the Klein-Gordon equation (relativistic scalar field), page 76, section 4.1

3)For the Dirac equation, page 123, section 5.2.

@Qmechanic Every time, Greiner postulates the relations for the fields and then ask himself if the annihilation/creation operators satisfy them also. 
Again, it seems we are just "changing coordinates" here.

Comment: @BySymmetry no. I'm in a quite introductory level, trying to connect standard quantum mechanics, classical mechanics and the beggining of QFT.